# CTE not working in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am writing a stored procedure when I am using CTE to use it in a C# application but for some reasons the stored procedure is not returning any data

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_GetBrokerData]
     @broker Varchar
as
Begin
    With CTE AS 
    (
        select   
            Product, Term,
            CASE 
                WHEN BidBroker = @broker THEN BidBroker 
                ELSE null 
            END AS BidBroker,
            CASE 
                WHEN BidBroker = @broker THEN BidVolume 
                ELSE null 
            END AS BidVolume,
            CASE 
                WHEN BidBroker = @broker THEN BidCP 
                ELSE null 
            END AS BidCP,
            CASE 
                WHEN BidBroker = @broker THEN Bid 
                ELSE null 
            END AS Bid,
            CASE WHEN OfferBroker = @broker THEN Offer ELSE null end as Offer,
            CASE WHEN OfferBroker = @broker THEN OfferCP ELSE null end as OfferCP,
            CASE WHEN OfferBroker = @broker THEN OfferVolume ELSE null end as OfferVolume,
            CASE WHEN OfferBroker = @broker THEN OfferBroker ELSE null end as OfferBroker
        from 
            canadiancrudes
   )
   Select * 
   From CTE 
   Where not (Bid is null and Offer is null)
End
```

May I know issue in the above procedure?

Comment: Does it return data when you run it in SSMS?  What does candiancrudes table look like?

Comment: Does irt return something without procedure?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri It does return the required data without a procedure

Comment: If I had to guess (and this is an educated guess) is that you are defining your parameter without length, meaning it's a `VARCHAR(1)`, and you don't have data of that length in your table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default len of variable with type `varchar` is 1. Simply change stored proc parameter type len on appropriate:

For example `@broker varchar(20)`

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that